# += operator does not call property setter

Tags: properties, c++builder-xe8

I am using the follow code in Embarcadero C++Builder XE8.

In Unit1.h:

```
private:    
  void     SetValue (Currency value);   
  Currency FValue;    

public:    
  __property Currency Value = {write= SetValue , read=FValue};
```

In Unit1.cpp:

```
void TForm1::SetValue(Currency _Value)   
{   
  FValue= _Value;   
  Label1->Caption= _Value;   
}
```

In the main program when I call:

```
  Value = 10;   // it calls SetValue and the Value will be set to 10   
  Value+= 10;   // it does not call SetValue and Value will not be set to 20
```

Why does `Value+= 10` not call `SetValue(20)`?

Comment: _"why does Value+= 10 does not call SetValue(20)"_ That's nothing to expect with standard c++, removed the tag.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use compound assignment operators with *properties*.  The compiler does not implement that, and never has.

`Value = 10;` is a direct assignment, so it invokes the property's **setter**, as expected.

`Value += 10;` **does not** translate to `Value = Value + 10;` like you are expecting. It actually invokes the property's **getter** to retrieve a temporary value, and then increments and assigns the temporary to itself.  The temporary is never assigned back to the property, which is why the property's **setter** is not called.  In other words, it translates to `temp = Value; temp += 10;`.

To do what you are attempting, you must explicitly use the `+` and `=` operators separately:

```
Value = Value + 10;
```